# How to insert data in oracle table from c#

Tags: c#, oracle

Im trying Oracle Table insert from c#, but see below error message.

Please help me, Thanks.

```
catch (OracleException oraex)
     {

         OracleCommand oracmd = new OracleCommand();

         oracmd.CommandText = "insert into abys_uavt.DMA_ERROR_LOG (Exception_Message) values('table or view does not exist')";

         oracmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     }
```

**Error Message:**

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Additional information
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `OracleCommand` instance is not associated with an open `OracleConnection` instance.

Comment: Thanks, its escaped me :)